# Create a subset of Bitmap without make a copy

Tags: android

I have this problem, when I try to make a new bitmap for another one, 
like this:

```
first_data = Bitmap.createBitmap(data, 0, 0, data.getWidth() / 2,data.getHeight()); 
second_data =  Bitmap.createBitmap(data, data.getWidth() / 2, 0, data.getWidth() / 2, 
data.getHeight() );
```

I meet an OutOfMemoryException...

If i use only the original full image I don't meet this issues, I think that Bitmap.createBitmap() make a copy of the original first image. 
There are a way to specify that I DON'T WANT make a copy of that? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check width and height in the debugger. Sounds like you're passing overly big bogus values there.

Comment: I think it works right, I have this issues only in a HTC Magic, if I try this code in a Samsung Galaxy S all is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems like:

- the BitMap.createBitmap()
  signature you are using is the
  correct way to 'subset' a bitmap
- that same method's [contract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,int,int,int,int%29)
  allows it to either return a view
  over the same bytes *or* to copy them

If your original bitmap were immutable (isMutable() == false), that would give some encouragement for it to return an object based on the same byte array, rather than copy the same.

To get an immutable bitmap, you could try createBitmap(Bitmap) and discard all references to the original (and/or use recycle())?

Comment: Thanks for your reply David,my Bitmap are downloaded by an asynctask and it isn't mutable: I verified this  with an Log.d(..).But exists a methods to verify if the image are copied or not?I know that bitmap images are allocated in native heap, but  how can I see the native heap status (free, allocated,used) and how can I free my bitmap? I have to set null the pointer only?Thanks a lot

Comment: See Bitmap.recycle() and various methods on java.lang.System.getRuntime() at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html

Comment: Looking at the latest Android sources, it would seem like the bit map is copied by allocating a new one and drawing into it.  http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java;h=dd83c3bfafba4e61687ce55ed21eb3522b874850;hb=HEAD